facing issue in CLMM raydium
It seems that the CLMM functions in the Raydium V1 DEX SDK have stopped working recently. After switching to V2, the V1 functions still aren’t functioning as expected. Could this be due to V1 being deprecated, or is there an alternative solution for maintaining compatibility with V1? Any insights or guidance on ensuring stable functionality across versions would be appreciated.
``
async function clmmCreatePool(clmmConfigId: string, startPoolPrice: any) {
try {
    const clmmAddress = input.CLMM.toString()
    const _ammConfig = (await formatClmmConfigs(clmmAddress))[clmmConfigId]
    const ammConfig: ClmmConfigInfo = { ..._ammConfig, id: new PublicKey(_ammConfig.id) }
    const makeCreatePoolInstruction = await Clmm.makeCreatePoolInstructionSimple({
        connection,
        programId: new PublicKey(clmmAddress),
        owner: userWallet.publicKey,
        mint1: tokenA,
        mint2: tokenB,
        ammConfig,
        initialPrice: startPoolPrice,
        startTime: input.startTime,
        makeTxVersion: TxVersion.V0,
        payer: userWallet.publicKey,
    })
    console.log(makeCreatePoolInstruction);
    // -------- step 2: get mockPool info --------
    const mockPoolInfo = Clmm.makeMockPoolInfo({
        programId: new PublicKey(clmmAddress),
        mint1: tokenA,
        mint2: tokenB,
        ammConfig,
        createPoolInstructionSimpleAddress: makeCreatePoolInstruction.address,
        owner: userWallet.publicKey,
        initialPrice: startPoolPrice,
        startTime: input.startTime
    })
    console.log(mockPoolInfo);

    const txids = await buildAndSendTx(userWallet,
        makeCreatePoolInstruction.innerTransactions,
        mockPoolInfo
    )
    console.log("\nCLMM Pool Address ", mockPoolInfo?.id.toString())
    console.log('Transaction Hash:', txids)
}
catch (error) {
    console.log("\nError Creating Pool Instruction ", error)
}

}
const clmmConfigId = 'B9H7TR8PSjJT7nuW2tuPkFC63z7drtMZ4LoCtD7PrCN1'
const startPoolPrice = new Decimal(1)
clmmCreatePool(clmmConfigId, startPoolPrice)
``
ERROR
'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: observation_state. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.',
